# Three level menu with css transitions

Tags: css, menu, css-transitions

I have this three level menu : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKmBD

I want to add opacity transitions to it so that when you hover on the level 1, the level 2 comes in with a transition.

Thank you

Comment: Please don't just link to codepen. Add relevant codes to your question so that it can stand on its own.

Answer (score 2):

You are using SCSS but I've made this in Pure CSS, you can translate it accordingly

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pAgBx)

Just add this to your CSS

```
ul li ul {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Also if you need more level down, just add elements in an order after ul li ul, /* Other declaration goes here */

Comment: @Stephen: you may need to use a browser that supports transitions with no vendor prefixes `-moz-` and such.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks Oh yes that may be the issue, if he needs more transitions down the levels than I need to create more nested declarations

Comment: I can't seem to get the nested declarations to work...http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKmBD as you can see the transitions affects all the levels...I would really appreciate the help